# How to check parameterised query result through pentaho cda file

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am going to cda file of specific dashboard. List of queries are coming, if I have tried query which is non parameterised then it is executing and data is coming.
But in case of parameterised query error is coming saying : Error Executing Query

So how can I check parameterised query result through cda ?

Edit 1:
If i pass default value in parameter then it works fine, and it is speially not working in case where i am using parameter for database name.

Comment: Issue is solved or not?

Comment: i can see the result if parameter is there in a query..
like select * from tablename where id=${id}

but i am not able to see the output if i am using parameter in database name like

select * from ${dbname}.tablename

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are passing the parameters correctly, have you assigned the listeners and parameters correctly? if you have the parameters type properly set, string or anything?

Comment: i have checked all this things..
i am clearly saying it is not working in database connection name scenario other then that it is working fine.